# What does "Still, you weren't eleven every day" mean in Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone?

Tags: meaning, grammar, grammaticality, meaning-in-context

The context:

> Monday. This reminded Harry of something. If it was Monday—and you
> could usually count on Dudley to know the days of the week, because of
> television—then tomorrow, Tuesday, was Harry’s eleventh birthday. Of
> course, his birthdays were never exactly fun — last year, the Dursleys
> had given him a coat hanger and a pair of Uncle Vernon’s old socks.
> *Still, you weren’t eleven every day.*
>
> — Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone
> by J. K. Rowling

I am wondering if this sentence is grammatical and correct to use here. If it is, please explain its meaning.

I guess Harry had never had a pleasant birthday since he was a baby, but that the eleventh was not to be like past ones.

Comment: How many eleventh birthdays does a person have in their life?

Comment: you mean It comes only once in a life? @ Michael Harvey

Comment: each age's birthday comes only once in a life. It is special.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common sentence; there is no complication about it, and moreover it is a pattern for thousands of sentences.

- You don't get married everyday. ( You didn't get married everyday.)
- It's not Christmas everyday. (It wasn't Christmas everyday.)
- You don't drink fifty year old whiskey everyday.

It means that whatever the  event that is being mentioned in the sentence, it is something important and rare in someone's life, and because of  that there is reason enough to make   the most of it or to take special precautions, or show  special attention to someone, etc.

Answer (score 1):

When one says something "[doesn't happen every day](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/it%20is%20not%20every%20day)," one means that the event happens rarely, and that one should take notice of it or celebrate it, despite whatever else is going on.

Harry is in a miserable situation with his mild-to-moderately abusive family and doesn't expect much worth celebrating.  Still, tomorrow is the only eleventh birthday he'll ever have, and he figures he might as well make the most of it.

Answer (score -1):

Let us start with *still*

> = despite that
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/still)

It is akin to:

> Nevertheless = despite what has just been said or referred to
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/)

The author’s use of *were* obliges me to put the following explanation in a past tense.

Harry is described as having recollected last year’s birthday, looked ahead to the next day’s birthday, expected some dull gift. He then is described as having thought that, despite these depressing reflections, a dull eleventh birthday only happens once.